# HTML table with scrollable body - not scrollable on mobile devices

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have created a simple HTML table that has a scrollable area.

Although the table looks and functions as expected from a desktop/laptop, when i view the table on a mobile device, for example an iPhone, the scrollbars are not visible.

How can i ensure the scrollbars are visible when viewing on mobile devices and tablets?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-controller="EventController">
<div class="outter">
    <table class="countries">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Country name</th>
                <td ng-repeat="countryNames in Countries">{{countryNames.countryName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Population</th>
                <td ng-repeat="population in Countries">{{ population.countryName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outter {
    width: 70%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.countries {
    width: 100%;

    tr {
        td {
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QW97X/4/

Answer (score 0):

In IOS you have to import some properties for scroll. Like
Important properties contentSize, contentInset, contentOffset, delegate.
for more details check this link.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_scrollview.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but your link is with reference to a native iOS app. I am asking about a web app.